# Can't create xamarin.ios native control wrapper

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, wrapper

I'm trying to create `xamarin wrapper` of this iOS native control. https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController.

I follow there instruction http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/binding_walkthrough/. 
I create iOS binding project, but I am not able to build project. There are errors:

```
Error BI1018: btouch: No [Export] attribute on property ECSliding.ECSlidingViewController.IsAnimated (BI1018) (ECSlidingBinding)
```

or

```
Error BI1018: btouch: No [Export] attribute on property ECSliding.ECSlidingViewController.ContainerView (BI1018) (ECSlidingBinding)
```

**ApiDefinitions.cs** (excerpt)

```
[BaseType (typeof (UIViewController))]
public partial interface ECSlidingViewController : IUIViewControllerContextTransitioning, IUIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator, IUIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext {

    [Static, Export ("slidingWithTopViewController:")]
    ECSlidingViewController SlidingWithTopViewController (UIViewController topViewController);

    [Export ("initWithTopViewController:")]
    IntPtr Constructor (UIViewController topViewController);

    [Export ("topViewController", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
    UIViewController TopViewController { get; set; }

    [Export ("underLeftViewController", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
    UIViewController UnderLeftViewController { get; set; }

    [Export ("underRightViewController", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
    UIViewController UnderRightViewController { get; set; }

    [Export ("anchorLeftPeekAmount")]
    float AnchorLeftPeekAmount { get; set; }

    [Export ("anchorLeftRevealAmount")]
    float AnchorLeftRevealAmount { get; set; }

    [Export ("anchorRightPeekAmount")]
    float AnchorRightPeekAmount { get; set; }

    [Export ("anchorRightRevealAmount")]
    float AnchorRightRevealAmount { get; set; }

    [Export ("anchorTopViewToRightAnimated:")]
    void AnchorTopViewToRightAnimated (bool animated);

    [Export ("anchorTopViewToRightAnimated:onComplete:")]
    void AnchorTopViewToRightAnimated (bool animated, Delegate complete);

    [Export ("anchorTopViewToLeftAnimated:")]
    void AnchorTopViewToLeftAnimated (bool animated);

    [Export ("anchorTopViewToLeftAnimated:onComplete:")]
    void AnchorTopViewToLeftAnimated (bool animated, Delegate complete);

    [Export ("resetTopViewAnimated:")]
    void ResetTopViewAnimated (bool animated);

    [Export ("resetTopViewAnimated:onComplete:")]
    void ResetTopViewAnimated (bool animated, Delegate complete);

    [Export ("topViewControllerStoryboardId", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
    string TopViewControllerStoryboardId { get; set; }

    [Export ("underLeftViewControllerStoryboardId", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
    string UnderLeftViewControllerStoryboardId { get; set; }

    [Export ("underRightViewControllerStoryboardId", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
    string UnderRightViewControllerStoryboardId { get; set; }

    [Export ("delegate", ArgumentSemantic.Assign)]
    ECSlidingViewControllerDelegate Delegate { get; set; }

    [Export ("topViewAnchoredGesture")]
    ECSlidingViewControllerAnchoredGesture TopViewAnchoredGesture { get; set; }

    [Export ("currentTopViewPosition")]
    ECSlidingViewControllerTopViewPosition CurrentTopViewPosition { get; }

    [Export ("panGesture", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
    UIPanGestureRecognizer PanGesture { get; }

    [Export ("resetTapGesture", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
    UITapGestureRecognizer ResetTapGesture { get; }

    [Export ("customAnchoredGestures", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]//, Verify ("NSArray may be reliably typed, check the documentation", "/Users/admin/Desktop/all/ECSlidingViewController1/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController.h", Line = 294)]
    NSObject [] CustomAnchoredGestures { get; set; }

    [Export ("isAnimated")]
    bool IsAnimated {get; set;}

    [Export ("containerView")]
    UIView ContainerView {get; set;}
}
```

Could you explain what could be the problem?

You can download the full project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ps3todqg1d7z0di/vxxNVqbBKq).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is a [series of bugs](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=16948) in Xamarin.iOS when inheriting from protocols in binding projects, like this:

```
public partial interface ECSlidingViewController :
    IUIViewControllerContextTransitioning,
    IUIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator, 
    IUIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext {
```

until this is fixed, try removing all those interfaces:

```
public partial interface ECSlidingViewController {
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same error and removed interface declaration didn't help. Any suggestions? @rolf-bjarne-kvinge